# How to get Chrome Extension Hotkeys working in Application Mode after update

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, desktop-application

I have a few Chrome extension that have hotkeys.
They all work in a normal Google Chrome window and for the past couple of years they worked without a problem in a Chrome Application Mode window.

But now my extension hotkeys have stopped working in Chrome App mode since Chrome updated to version 50.0.2661.94 m

They still work ok in a normal window.

---

A Chrome Application Mode window allows you to open a site without all the Browser UI with an Application look.

To create one :

[image]

---

[image]

Note the Open as window.

---

On the Desktop you get an Alias/ Link file.

[image]

---

When opened you have a sparse UI.

[image]

---

I am the developer of the extensions and I have not change anything there.

I have added the `--enable-extensions` to the end of the Target, even though I did not need that before but that does not work.

[image]

I cannot downgrade the Chrome and there is noting to change in the extensions.

It looks like all extensions hotkey calls are not getting through to the app Mode window.

Does anyone else have this problem and more importantly can any one help with a fix.

Comment: According to this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/d5NRKcqe5KQ), you can try older versions of Chrome by downloading it from this [link](http://www.oldapps.com/google_chrome.php). Tell us if you're successful so we can confirm that it is indeed the new update that's causing the problem.

Comment: Hi @noogui  , my problem is I cannot do this as these are not a personal PCs. So I cannot download and install a different version of Chrome.

Comment: Here's for [Macs](https://google-chrome.en.uptodown.com/mac/old)

Comment: @noogui but I need an answer for PCs